# Why does a gluon soft factor depend only on the adjacent legs?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-chromodynamics, spinors, s-matrix-theory, helicity

The gluon soft factor can be obtained by taking the soft gluon limit in the $n$-point MHV amplitude $$A(1,2,\cdots, n)=\frac{\langle i,j\rangle^4}{\langle 1,2\rangle\cdots\langle n, 1\rangle},$$ to be $$S_{YM}=\frac{\langle n-1, 1\rangle}{\langle n-1, n\rangle\langle n, 1\rangle},$$ where we have taken the $n^{\text{th}}$ gluon soft. However, a Feynman diagrammatic approach yields: $$S'_{YM}=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{\langle p_i, l\rangle}{\langle p_i, n\rangle\langle n, l\rangle},$$ where we sum over soft gluon emissions from all external legs $p_i$, and $l$ is the momentum of an arbitrary reference leg.

Now, the above obtained soft factors are supposed to match only if the sum runs over the legs adjacent to the soft gluon, however in that case I get $$S'_{YM}=\left(\frac{\langle n-1, l\rangle}{\langle n-1, n\rangle\langle n, l\rangle}+\frac{\langle 1, l\rangle}{\langle 1, n\rangle\langle n, l\rangle}\right),$$ which is not equal to $S_{YM}$. However, if I somehow flip the sign of the first term, then the terms do combine and using Schouten identity, the equality can be shown. Is there any explanation of why the signs should be so? I believe that it has got something to do with the colour ordered nature of the amplitudes, but don't have a clear idea.